# SQL Data to javascript Chart

Tags: php, mysql

i have a data stored in sql , how can i get that data into the chart?
when i use to store sql data to separate json file, its overwrite the old data with new data
i am using `json_encode` function of php

here is my sql code:

```
$json = mysql_query("SELECT * from forms where User_ID = $user_id AND Leave_Type = 'PTO'");
while($get_sql = mysql_fetch_array($json)){
  $array[] = $get_sql;
}

$encode_sql = json_encode($array);

$myfile = fopen("data.json", "w");
$hello = "Hello world";
fwrite($myfile, $encode_sql);
```

Comment: So why are you mixing 2 things? Chart and writing in file?

Comment: i would recommend that you let your php output the json data and access the data via ajax from the clients side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your JSON data into an array that PHP can use to generate the chart server-side, then use `json_decode()`  to convert JSON data into a PHP array.

If you want to render the chart client-side, then use an ajax call by either downloading a third party javascript framework that implements ajax functions, or create the XHR request yourself.

I would recommend using **jQuery** or **w3.JS**  for the javascript solution

### EDIT

Examples:

SQL Code:

```
$array = array();
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "SELECT * from forms where User_ID = $user_id AND Leave_Type = 'PTO'";
  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) { 
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
         $array[] = $obj;
        }
    $result->close(); 
    }

print_r(json_encode($array));
```

Then from the web page:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
$.getJSON("sql.php", function(result)) {  /* generate your chart */ });
```